# What's the difference between the following state?

Tags: ios, objective-c, synthesize

maybe it's a little childish question, but I really want to know the detail. I've just seen this code:

```
@implementation SimpleMainViewController
{
    SimpleTableViewController *simpleTableViewController;
    AboutViewController *aboutViewController;
}
```

what's the difference between this and the following one?

```
@interface SimpleMainViewController : UIViewController
@property(nonatomic,retain) SimpleTableViewController *simpleTableViewController;
@property(nonatomic,retain) AboutViewController *aboutViewController;

@implementation SimpleMainViewController
@synthesize simpleTableViewController;
@synthesize aboutViewController;
```

Thanks in forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is only visible and acceseable from inside the implemented class. It is called an instance variable.

Whereas the property is visible to other classes as well. A property is backed by an iVar too.  The `@synthesize` is doing this behind the scenes. In your case the backing iVar would be accessable with the name of the property (e.g. `simpleViewController`). But one should access a property via self (e.g. `self.simpleViewController`) for simpler memory management and to distinguish it from an normal iVar. The `@synthesize` will generate getter and setters to the iVar and will do memory management according to the property declaration (here retain).

Nowadays you do not even need a `@synthesize` any more. Just declare a property. The compiler will create the property with an backing iVar with a prefix underscore. So one could access it either via `self.simpleTableViewController` or via `_simpleTableViewController`.

Comment: Thanks for your attention! And they don't have any other differences at all?

Comment: They are different! Added more infos to the answer.

Comment: Great answer, very concise and helpful. +1